# How to store read-in data element by element in a memory-efficient way?

Tags: python, list, memory, split, readlines

The program I'm working on needs to read in data files which can be quite large (up to 5GB) in ASCII. The format can vary that's why I came up with using `readline()`, split every line to get just the pure entries, append them all to one big list of strings and divide this one in smaller string lists depending on the occurrence of certain marker words, and then pass the data to a program internal data structure for further unified processing.
This method is working good enough except that it **needs way to much memory** and I wonder why.

So I wrote this little test case which makes you understand my problem:
The input data here is the text of Shakespears Romeo and Juliet (actually I expect mixed alphabetic - numeric input) - note that I want you to copy the data yourself to keep things clearly. The script generates a .txt file which is then read in again using. The **origina**l memory size in this case is **153 KB**.
Reading this file with...

- f.read() gives you a single string with a size of **153 KB**, too.
- f.readlines() gives you a list with single strings for every line with a overall size of **420 KB**.
- Splitting the line strings of f.readlines() at every whiespace and save all those single entries in a new list results in **1619 KB** in memory use.

As these numbers don't seem to be a **problem** in this cases, a factor of >10 in **increase of RAM requiremen**t is definitly one for input data in GB order.

I don't have any idea why this is or how to avoid this. From my point of understanding a list is just a structure of pointers pointing on all the values stored in the list (this is also the reason, why sys.getsizeof() on a list gives you a 'wrong' result).
For the values themself it shouldn't make a difference in memory if I have "LONG STRING" or "LONG" + "STRING" as both use the same characters which should result in the same amount of bits/bytes.

Maybe the answer is really simple but I am really stuck with this problem so I am thankful for every idea.

```
# step1: http://shakespeare.mit.edu/romeo_juliet/full.html
# step2: Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+C
# step3: Ctrl+V after benchmarkText

benchmarkText = """ >>INSERT ASCII DATA HERE<< """

#=== import modules =======================================
from pympler import asizeof
import sys

#=== open files and safe data to a structure ==============
#-- original memory size
print("\n\nAll memory sizes are in KB:\n")
print("Original string size:")
print(asizeof.asizeof(benchmarkText)/1e3)
print(sys.getsizeof(benchmarkText)/1e3)

#--- write bench mark file
with open('benchMarkText.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(benchmarkText)

#--- read the whole file (should always be equal to original size)
with open('benchMarkText.txt', 'r') as f:
    # read the whole file as one string
    wholeFileString = f.read()    
    # check size:
    print("\nSize using f.read():")
    print(asizeof.asizeof(wholeFileString)/1e3)

#--- read the file in a list
listOfWordOrNumberStrings = []
with open('benchMarkText.txt', 'r') as f:
    # safe every line of the file
    listOfLineStrings = f.readlines()
    print("\nSize using f.readlines():")
    print(asizeof.asizeof(listOfLineStrings)/1e3)

    # split every line into the words or punctation marks
    for stringLine in listOfLineStrings:
        line = stringLine[:-1] # get rid of the '\n'
       # line = re.sub('"', '', line) # The final implementation will need this, however for the test case it doesn't matter.
        elemsInLine = line.split()
        for elem in elemsInLine:
            listOfWordOrNumberStrings.append(elem)
    # check size
    print("\nSize after splitting:")
    print(asizeof.asizeof(listOfWordOrNumberStrings)/1e3)
```

(I am aware that I use readlines() instead of readline() here - I changed it for this test case because I think it makes things easier to understand.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question? Are you asking why this seems to take a lot of memory? Note, creating a lot of little strings uses a ton of overhead, each string object requires around 49 bytes of overhead (so, an empty string requires 49 bytes)

Comment: So, `'abc'` requires 52 byes, but `'a` and `'bc'` (two separate objects) would require `50 +51` bytes

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah this is exactly what I didn't understand! Thank you very much for this information. I wasn't aware that even a simple string or integer is an object in python.

I read a bit more on this overhead topic here: [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609)

Is there a way to avoid those overheads in python, like a _string_ _list_ instead of a normal _list_ where this overhead would be outsourced to the _string_ _list_?